# Do you have any suggestions for a content (image) slider in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, gallery, uipagecontrol

I have an UIPageControl by now. It works good but the problem is, that if there are a lot if pictures it looks like that:

[image]

Normally it looks like that:

[image]

So what can I do when there are too many points? Or is there another appropriate solution?

Comment: Why not build your own thats just a label that displays, e.g. `3 / 75`, `4 / 75`, `5 / 75`

Comment: Nice idea but i think a page control looks better than this one. I will keep your solution anyway in mind